# Which CSS could replace a text (1 symbol) of the Main Menu by a longer text on Mobile Responsive view?

Tags: css, replace, menu, menuitem

Because of a "Dashboard" link missing in the menu of my WP theme Listingpro, on responsive view only. A link to Dashboard is already there and working well on Desktop view.

I thought about adding a text symbol, this symbol could be: ◊ , on the right side of the Main (homepage, top bar, Mobile) menu. This symbol linked to Dashboard and could give access to students (users that has logged in already) to their listing Dashboard. So they are able to access and edit from their mobile device.

If not log in yet, and someone clicks the dashboard link, it is already going to the Home Page.

Lisitngpro has already created an Apps view, that fixes this issue, where the dashboard link works well, but I cannot use this Apps view because of some customization on the search bar. So I need a solution.

So I added the symbol ◊ on the right Top Menu, next to the Login button.
It looks something like this on Desktop:

Schedule | Training | contact us | ◊ | Login

and like that on responsive view:

Login  Schedule
Training
contact us
◊

->  1) A custom CSS code could replace this symbol (that is not used in my entire site), on Mobile responsive only, by a sentence “Student Dashboard”.   So it could be looking like this on Responsive view:

Login  Schedule
Training
contact us
Student Dashboard

-> 2) Ideally, it could make the replacement text appears only once logged in.

->    3) Ideally, it could also make the replacement text never appears on Desktop view, as the link already exists on the Desktop view.  But success with 1) will be already great !!!

Could someone help me with a CSS, any clue ?

thanks ,
Sylvain

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries to control the content before and after some elements. The example below uses very generic selectors, please adapt it for your own web site.
(if it's not what you're looking for, feel free to tell me in the comments.)

```css
/* This uses global rules. Adapt for
your own site! */

#menubar {
  position:sticky;
  position:-webkit-sticky;
  top:0;
  margin:0px;
  left:10;
  background-color:white;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
* {
  margin:0px;
}
body {
  margin:0px;
}
li {
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color:cyan;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  li {
    display:block;
  }
  #home::before {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    content:"◊";
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  li {
    display:inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="menubar">
  <ul>
    <li id="home">HOME</li>
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit sollicitudin urna, et tempus purus sollicitudin non. Fusce blandit neque venenatis mauris varius consequat. Nam fermentum mi vel accumsan ultrices.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit sollicitudin urna, et tempus purus sollicitudin non. Fusce blandit neque venenatis mauris varius consequat. Nam fermentum mi vel accumsan ultrices.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit sollicitudin urna, et tempus purus sollicitudin non. Fusce blandit neque venenatis mauris varius consequat. Nam fermentum mi vel accumsan ultrices.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your CSS above , 
On appearence/Custom CSS, I am getting a red color on Menubar and Home with error: Markup is not allowed in CSS. 

<div id="menubar">
  <ul>
    <li id="home">HOME</li>

Also, I am just a little confused. I can see the Symol ◊, but can't see the wanted text replacement (Student Dashboard). Do these have to be added on the line<p> Lorem ipsum dolor si..</p> for option 1, and so on for option 2 and 3?

thanks  ,
Sylvain